# Removing List tag and single quotes in django template

Tags: django, dataframe, list, django-templates, django-filter

I've created dataframe. Showing that data on front end side using django templates.

Like mentioned here:
[image]

In that dataframe getting list for `Business Segment` column.

But I want to remove that list and single quotes and show it like `Bag | Cement`.

How can I do this using django template filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's template tag [join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#join) to concat your list values with characters of your choice:

```
{{ business_segment_list|join:" | " }}
```